# How to write custom onclick function for simplemaps circles

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a map from Simplemaps. When clicking on a chosen circle (location/marker) I don't want to be redirected to the specified url. I want to do something else and I am just trying to console.log something onclick. I tried passing a function rather than the redirect url. I tried clicking on a circle or the element with the class.

```
$('circle').on('click', function() {
    console.log('adsadas');
});

$('.sm_location_2').on('click', function() {
        console.log('adsadas');
});
```

All of these didn't work. Any idea how can I achieve that?

Comment: I think you looking for https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: [do you want something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/9bnCw/64/)

Comment: No. I need to use a map provided by simplemaps.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
$('circle').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
console.log('adsadas');
});
```

This should work

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work. Also tried it for another element to make sure that it logs something and it works. It seems like the 'circle' element is the problem.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?